# how to handle unfurtunately close caused by low speed of Internet in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-volley

When I run my project, it goes to `JSONException` catch and the unfortunately closed **stops** my project
I don't have an error and think it's because of my Internet.
I want my app doesn't closed but instead just  show a message.
How should I do that ?
Thanks for any help

Comment: load a Progressdialogue untill it recieves a data

Comment: I think your JSON response is not proper or something wrong with your code. And don't come to the conclusion that this error/exception is due to Slow Network before verifying whether your code is proper or not. So, [edit] the question and post [mcve] here (your JSON response and code which raises Exception). Without looking into the code for us it's very difficult to help.